# Java Web Service with Oracle 12c query result set caching

Tags: java, oracle12c, jdeveloper

I have developed simple web service that pull data from oracle database using JDeveloper , the data returned as expected , the problem when i manually delete from database using "delete from table name where condition" and make new request through the web service the result returned as is before the deletion.

this the method that read from the db

```
    private int GetStudnetRequests(int STID,int SEMID) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int TotalReq = 0;
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT count(*) from REQUESTS where ID=? and SEM=? ";
        prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        prepStmt.setInt(1, STID);
        prepStmt.setInt(2, SEMID);
        rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            TotalReq = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Number of Request" + TotalReq);
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (prepStmt != null)
                prepStmt.close();
                closeDB();
                rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return TotalReq;
}
```

the TotalReq not changed after i delete from the db , it keep gives me the last value

here how i call this method

```
                if ((GetStudnetRequests(STID,SEMID) <= NumofRequests)) {
                output = BuildOutput(true, "success");
                InsertRequest(STID, COURSEID, SEMID); // create request on suc
            }
```

Comment: Is the data row available in the DB? Or did you fired commit statement after deleting the record?

Comment: actually in the DB but i didn't fire any commit, i will commit and updates

Comment: Many thanks , it solved , but i wonder do i need to commit from the method above too , i am a little bit confused.

Comment: This link https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/getsta.htm#JJDBC28071 might help you to understand it in a better way.

Comment: Every time you _modify_ data in the DB, it needs to be followed by a commit for the changes to become visible to other transactions.

Comment: Many thanks appreciate your help .